# Restore old undumped MySQL database to new Wamp Server

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I always install my Wamp Server to `D:` partition not to `C:` partition.

I've just formatted `C:` partition but forgotten to dump my databases.

My old databases are still in `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data\[database-name]` like `*.frm, *.MYD, *.MYI` files.

I didn't install wamp server yet.

So; what should i do now to reinstall Wamp Server and restore my old database(s).

Could you please tell it step by step?

Answer (score 0):

If you use only MyISAM storages and never used InnoDB you just find your my.ini and find line

```
datadir=...
```

and make sure it is like

```
datadir=D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data\
```

If you are using InnoDB you need to adjust

```
innodb_log_file_size=...
```

to size of yours ib_logfile*  files which are placed in D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data\

Comment: I don't know MYISAM or InnoDB. I just installed Wamp Server and used PhpMyAdmin

Comment: If you can find ib_logfile* there it 'll be a good idea to adjust parameter innodb_log_file_size=  Just do it..